# Hive: Conditionally truncate and load the table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to resolve the issue where if all categories of source table is available in target then truncate and load the target table else don't do anything.

I haven't found any solution just using hive and end up using **Shell script** as well to resolve this issue.

**is it possible to avoid shell script?**

**Current Approach:**

**create_ind_table.hql**:

```
create temporary table temp.master_source_join
as select case when source.program_type_cd=master.program_type_cd then 1 else 0 end as IND
from source left join master
    on source.program_type_cd=master.program_type_cd;

--if all the categoies from source persent in master then will contain 1 else 0'
drop table if exists temp.indicator;
create table temp.indicator
as select min(ind)*max(ind) as ind from master_source_join;
```

And following is the script I am calling to Truncate and load the master table if all the source table categories are present in master.

**tuncate_load_master.sh**

```
beeline_cmd="beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://abc.com:2181,abc1.com:2181,abc2.com:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2' --showHeader=flase --silent=true"
${beeline_cmd} -f create_ind_table.hql
## if indicator is 1 all the source category is present in master else not.

a=`${beeline_cmd} -e "select ind from temp.indicator;"`
temp=`echo $a | sed -e 's/-//g' | sed -e 's/+//g' | sed -e 's/|//g'`
echo $temp
if [ ${temp} -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "truncate and load the traget table"
    ${beeline_cmd} -e "insert overwrite table temp.master select * from temp.source;"
else
    echo "nothing to load"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query with dynamic partitioning will overwrite only partitions existing in the source dataset. Add a dummy partition to your table, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505850/2700344

You can calculate your flag using analytic `min()` in the same subquery and filter by it.

IND calculated will be the same for all rows returned. And it seems analytic min() is enough, no need to calculate max(). Filter by IND=1. It will return no rows if `min() over()`=0 and will not overwrite the table.

```
--enable dynamic partitioning
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert overwrite table temp.master PARTITION(dummy_part) 
select s.col1, s.col2, --list all columns here you need to insert 
        'dummy_value' as dummy_part --dummy partition column 
from 
(
select s.*, 
      min(case when s.program_type_cd=m.program_type_cd then 1 else 0 end ) over() as IND
from source s left join master m
    on s.program_type_cd=m.program_type_cd
)s where ind=1 --filter will not return rows if min=0
```

Comment: insert overwrite actually truncates the table if select does not return any row.  And that's the reason I am using shell script.

Comment: @GaurangShah Yes, forgot about this feature. Please see my updated answer. Propose to add dummy partition and use dynamic partitioning. It will add one more directory level to the data location, everything else remains the same.

Comment: could you please let me know why insert overwrite with truncate the table if I don't use partition however won't if I use partition.

Comment: @GaurangShah Probably it will overwrite if you specify partition statically, I'm not sure. But if partition selected from dataset and dataset did not return it, how will it know which partition to rewrite. And it overwrites only partitions from dataset, not all partitions existing in the table. Maybe correct and short answer is "by design"